# isotope resort without moving the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to implement the [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) lib so elements sort around my menu. After some research and tooling around I opted to set the first element in the isotope container as the menu item. I then filter it out of any manipulation I do as far as filtering or sorting.

I opted for this method as opposed to the corner-stamp method due to limitations on corner-stamping only working on elements right justified (from what I understand - I could just be miss using it though..). I'd like the menu to be in the top left hand corner.

The problem I'm running into is on shuffle. I'm trying to randomize the positions of all elements EXCEPT the first element (in this example the menu). I want to keep the menu in its place. When I try to use the shuffle to randomly reorder all the elements, I can't filter out my menu item from the available list to shuffle. This causes some navigation.. issues when the sub nav decides to fly away.

Here is an example layout: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/xwpuk/30/

So far I've tried:  `$('.container').isotope('shuffle');`

This function only has 1 parameter - a callback. I don't see how I could manipulate the selection process here.

I've considered using the sort function, but for some reason I cannot get:
`$('.container').isotope({ sortBy : 'random' });` to fire more than once. Even if I did I still don't see how I could leverage this to filter out my menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT :** Updated jsFiddle link to include numbers on the sortable objects - helps show sorting work.

**EDIT 2 :** Added more detail to issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe isotope caches sorts so it doesn't have to recalculate a sort that it has already done.  It even does this on "random" it seems.

A fix/hack is to `reloadItems` after the random sort:

```
$('#reorder').click(function () {
    $('.container').isotope({sortBy: 'random'}).isotope('reloadItems');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nT66r/

As for filtering the menu item, random simply returns a random number, so there is not a lot you can do.  However,  you can write a custom random sort which would allow you to "filter" the menu:

```
getSortData: {
    name: function ($elem) {
        return $elem.data('name');
    },
    myrandom: function ($elem) {
        if($elem.hasClass('menu')) {
             return -1;   
        }
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PvnMn/

Note, because `menu` is a class, you leave yourself open to some possible weirdness if there are multiple `menu` items.  If you only have one, an ID is a better choice.  In that case, you would use `$elem.is('#menu')` instead of `$elem.hasClass('menu')`.

With `#menu`: http://jsfiddle.net/PvnMn/1/

Here is a version with my stab at filtering for other sorts: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/Vuqgu/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It worked the first time I tried it, but on subsequent sorts and page loads it reordered at random again.

Good info to know though, I didn't realize it cached the values for sorts.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to reorder at random?  Sorry, it is not clear to me what problem you are having.

Comment: Ah sorry for the vague question.  I'm trying to shuffle all elements BUT the first element (the menu). So I'd like the menu to stay in place as the first element and have all other isotope elements reorder randomly. I updated the question a bit for clarity.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a ton man. I would have never guessed that its returning a number for random. Thats pretty clever and not nearly as complex as I assumed it would be.